# Significance of exclamation marks in comments in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, coding-style, comments

I have seen programmers using comments like following format:

```
/*! This is a sample comment
*/
```

I have seen such comments for the first time while ios development i.e in objective-c.
What is the significance of '!'(exclamation mark) here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the introductionary tag for [HeaderDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/tags/tags.html)

You usually see it in a comment that is "linked" to a method, function or variable.

e.g.:

```
/*!
 This is a comment about FunctionName.
*/
char *FunctionName(int k);
```

If you use those comments in Xcode 5.1 you can have those documentation popovers (Option + click on methods) for your own code:

[image]

So expect to see those things more frequently in the future. :-)

And if you want to use them yourself, I would recommend to have a look at [VVDocumenter](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode), a Xcode plugin that makes the creation of those a bit easier.

Comment: Yeah!!
I have seen this just above the function declarations.